# Getting a "1" at the end of JOptionOutput

Tags: java

Simple program to just find the circumference, diameter, and area of a circle. Whenever I run the program it's fine, just at the end there's always a 1 or -1 after the value for Area. For example, when using a radius of 10 I get:

> Results
>   The circumference of the circle is: 62.832 Centimeters
>   The diameter of the circle is: 20.0 Centimeters
>   The area of the circle is: 314.159 Centimeters1

Code is as follows below:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Circle {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    //Declarations
    double radius;
    String getRadius;

    //Formatting
    DecimalFormat formatter = new
    DecimalFormat(".000");

    //Calculations
    getRadius = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Circle Radius In Centimeters:");
    radius = Double.parseDouble(getRadius);

    //Output
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Results" + 
            "\n The circumference of the circle is: " + formatter.format(2*Math.PI*radius) + " Centimeters" +
            "\n The diameter of the circle is: " + 2*radius + " Centimeters" +
            "\n The area of the circle is: " + formatter.format(Math.PI*Math.pow(radius,2)) + " Centimeters" +
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending `JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE` (which happens to equal 1) to your string.  It should be something like:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
        "Results" + 
        "\n The circumference of the circle is: " + formatter.format(2*Math.PI*radius) + " Centimeters" +
        "\n The diameter of the circle is: " + 2*radius + " Centimeters" +
        "\n The area of the circle is: " + formatter.format(Math.PI*Math.pow(radius,2)) + " Centimeters", 
        "Results", 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

The four parameters are parent, message, title, messageType.  Before, you were accidentally using the two-parameter version (parent, message) and appending the messageType to your message.

Comment: This was it. It took me a second to figure out what you meant with the four parameters but then I realized what the comma was acting as. You've pretty much made me see this completely differently so thank you.